# How to write XSD to validate escaped xml data pattern

Tags: java, xml, regex, xsd, xsd-validation

I got a specific xml data below

```
<l7:ApiPlans xmlns:l7="http://ns.xcompany.com/2012/04/api-management">
  <l7:ApiPlan>
<l7:PlanPolicy>

&lt;wsp:Policy xmlns:L7p="http://www.xcompany.com/ws/policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy"&gt;
&lt;wsp:All wsp:Usage="Required"&gt;
    &lt;wsp:All wsp:Usage="Required"&gt;
          ...... some other welformed xml
&lt;/wsp:All&gt;
    &lt;/wsp:All&gt;
&lt;/wsp:Policy&gt;
    </l7:PlanPolicy>
  </l7:ApiPlan>
</l7:ApiPlans>
```

That I need to write an XSD (if possible) to validate that PlanPolicy starts with

```
&lt;wsp:Policy xmlns:L7p="http://www.xcompany.com/ws/policy"     
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy"&gt;
&lt;wsp:All wsp:Usage="Required"&gt;
    &lt;wsp:All wsp:Usage="Required"&gt;
```

and ends with

```
 &lt;/wsp:All&gt;
        &lt;/wsp:All&gt;
    &lt;/wsp:Policy&gt;
```

So far I have this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ns.xcompany.com/2012/04/api-management" xmlns:l7="http://ns.xcompany.com/2012/04/api-management">
<xs:element name="ApiPlans">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="l7:ApiPlan"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="ApiPlan">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>               
            <xs:element ref="l7:PlanPolicy"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="PlanPolicy" type="policyDataType"/>
<simpleType name="policyDataType">
    <restriction base="xs:string">
         <minLength value="1"></minLength>
        <pattern value="(&lt;).*(&gt;).*(&lt;).*(&gt;)"></pattern>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Is that possible? And as a side question, How do you define in pattern: new lines(CR/LF), tab and quotes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible, and regular expressions are about your only option with this untypical task.  Note that the escaped content will not be processed as XML, but rather as a string.

Be sure to read how to properly [escape various special characters](http://www.xmlschemareference.com/regularExpression.html#Metacharacters), including parentheses, in the regular expression.

Newline and tab are represented by `\n` and `\t`m respectively.

Quotes can be entered by doubling them up.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't try to do it this way.

Well, given half a choice, I would never use escaped XML within XML anyway - XML is designed to be nested without escaping, and escaping it just makes everyone's life more difficult.

But if you have to live with it like this, I would validate the inner XML separately after extracting it and parsing it. There is no need to do everything in one validation pass.

Comment: i was actually thinking of doing this as well. but unfortunately i am stuck with a propriety way to perform this task. i can probably used